# Compare each item with its next item and find each item big or small by comparing. And push the result to a new array for each

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, compare

I have an array like the one below. How can I find every single value in the array is small or big compare to its next value. And I want to push the result in a new array like this same array. And if the items is the same then that's will be empty.

```
const array = [
[7, 10, 10, 10, 9, 13, 9, 9, 11, 12, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[6, 5, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6],
[7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
[0, 63, 58, 65, 55, 68, 65, 65, 43, 58, 57, 55, 55, 70, 55],
[29, 26, 28, 27, 29, 29, 30, 33, 32, 33, 28, 28, 31, 31, 29],
[3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
];
```

This is my code but which is doesn't work.

```
const items = [];
  function getOutRank() {
array.map((singleKey, index) => {
  console.log("SINGLE KEY", singleKey);
  for (let i = 0; i < singleKey.length; i++) {
    if (singleKey[i + 1] > singleKey[i]) {
      return items.push(<span key={index}>Down</span>);
    }
    if (singleKey[i + 1] === singleKey[i]) {
      return items.push(<span key={index} />);
    }
    return items.push(<li key={index}>Up</li>);
  }
});}

getOutRank();
```

Answer (score 1):

For each `singleKey`, an array of all the compare results should be returned. Try like this:

```js
const array = [
  [7, 10, 10, 10, 9, 13, 9, 9, 11, 12, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [6, 5, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6],
  [7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
  [0, 63, 58, 65, 55, 68, 65, 65, 43, 58, 57, 55, 55, 70, 55],
  [29, 26, 28, 27, 29, 29, 30, 33, 32, 33, 28, 28, 31, 31, 29],
  [3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
];

let items = [];

function getOutRank() {
  items = array.map((singleKey, index) => {
    var compare = [];
    
    for (let i = 0; i < singleKey.length - 1; i++) {
      if (singleKey[i + 1] > singleKey[i]) {
        compare.push(`<span key=${index}>Down</span>`);
      } else if (singleKey[i + 1] === singleKey[i]) {
        compare.push(`<span key=${index}>Equal</span>`);
      } else {
        compare.push(`<li key=${index}>Up</li>`);
      }
    }
    
    return compare;
  });
}

getOutRank();
console.log(items);
```

Comment: Is there any others way to do that, which can more efficient?

Comment: Are you having efficiency issues?

Comment: Not yet but, there can be thousand and thousand of data in the future.